# Ninject doesn't make implementation of interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, ninject

I'm unable to make Ninject work in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project.
It doesn't want to make the concrete object connected to the interface and I'm out of ideas what could fix this.

My project has an interface `IQuizRepository` in `Domain.Abstract` which consists of only `ICollection<Quiz> Quizes { get; }`
The implementation is `QuizRepository` in `Domain.Concrete` and looks like this:

```
public class QuizRepository : IQuizRepository
{
    public ICollection<Quiz> Quizes { get; private set; }

    public QuizRepository()
    {
        List<Quiz> quizes = new List<Quiz>();
        // adding some Quiz objects to the list
        Quizes = quizes;
    }
}
```

The controller is `Website.Controllers.HomeController.cs` which simply tests if Ninject works and looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(IQuizRepository quiz)
{
    ViewBag.test = quiz.Quizes.First().Id;
    return View();
}
```

`NinjectWebCommon` which is in `Website.App_Start` is equal to the default generated one except the `RegisterServices` method:

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon 
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

                RegisterServices(kernel);
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<Domain.Abstract.IQuizRepository>().To<Domain.Concrete.QuizRepository>();
        }        
    }
```

It still fails to make the implementation of `IQuizRepository`.
I think I have all the NuGet packages installed that are required:

```
Ninject v3.2.0.0
Ninject.MVC5 v3.2.1.0
Ninject.Web.Common v3.2.0.0
Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost v3.2.0.0
```

The stacktrace (sadly partly in Dutch since I can't get the error messages to show in English):

```
[MissingMethodException: Kan geen exemplaar van een interface maken.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +232
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +197

[MissingMethodException: Kan geen exemplaar van een interface maken. Object type 'Domain.Abstract.IQuizRepository'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +233
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +532
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +330
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +331
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +105
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +743
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +465
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__14(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +18
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +374
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +384
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your NinjectWebCommon file, you need to change the last method (Private RegisterServices) to something like this:

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
    }
```

Then you need to add a NinjectDependencyResolver.cs file like this:

```
    public class NinjectDependencyResolver: IDependencyResolver {
        private readonly IKernel _kernel;

        public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel) {
            _kernel = kernel;
            AddBindings();
        }
        public object GetService(Type serviceType) {
            return _kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType) {
            return _kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
        }

        private void AddBindings() {
            // PULL YOUR BINDINGS HERE
            _kernel.Bind<Domain.Abstract.IQuizRepository>().To<Domain.Concrete.QuizRepository>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, just because I ran into this a few times.  Make sure you delete out your bin folder.  If you have renamed any of your libraries, they may still exist in the Bin folder and Ninject will attempt to inspect them and blow up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm getting the exact same answer. Have deleted the bin folders, tried cleaning the solution in Visual Studio and moved the bindings to `Website.Infrastructure.NinjectDependencyResolver.cs` the stacktrace and error remain exactly the same.  I've uploaded the complete files to pastebin: [NinjectDependencyResolver](http://pastebin.com/eU0hiRWX) & [NinjectWebCommon](http://pastebin.com/haFtLYhu)

Comment: In your Website.Controllers.HomeController.cs do you have this: `public class HomeController: Controler{
 private IQuizRepository _quizRepo;
 
 public HomeController(IQuizRepository repo){
  _quizRepo = repo;
 }
}`

Comment: Yes thanks! That did the trick. The problem was that I asked for the implementation in the `Index()` method. Moving it to the constructor and making the repo an instance variable did it!

Comment: You can do the implementation at the method level.  Here are the patterns: [link](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns)

Comment: Good to know, but it looks like it is only possible on the method level if it is a setter method. At least it didn't work for my `Index()` method.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, Ninject by default does not allow that.  You could create your own attribute to handle it.